# git: how to create branch from commits and revert the commits?

Tags: git

I have this scenario:

- I created a series of commits and pushed to the central repository. Others have pushed their own commits. So the history is (Myx are my commits, Ox are others' commits):

> ```
> master ...->My1-->My2-->O1-->O2
> ```

- Now I've found a serious bug in my commits. I want to create a branch and revert my commits. This creates this history (Myx' are the reverting commits, O3 is another commit by others):

> ```
> master ...->My1-->My2-->O1-->O2--My1'-->My2'-->O3
>                     \
>                 fix  \--
> ```

The problem is that if I now merge `master` to `fix`, then this will merge My1' and My2' which will revert the code in fix, which is not what I want.

What is the proper way to handle this scenario? My current approach would be to cherry-pick O1,O2,O3, but this sounds too manual & error prone, so I'm looking if there is a better way (maybe another way to create the branch & revert the commits to begin with?). I can't rewrite the history, since everything is already in the central repository

UPDATE: to emphasize, the scenario is that the bug is a blocker and cannot be easily fixed. The feature is also not something that can be toggled in code. So reverting the feature in master is a must to get the code base back to working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do a rebase and edit the commit where the bug occurs. If it happened in My1 and you're at O2 then you'd want to do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

You'll then be presented with something like this:

```
pick 880606e My1
pick 9e84c00 My2
pick 17e4289 O1
pick 73b8f2e O2

# Rebase aab4d7f..73b8f2e onto aab4d7f
#
# Commands:
#  pick = use commit
#  edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

For the commit you want to edit, delete the word pick and replace it with an 'e' or 'edit':

```
e 880606e My1
pick 9e84c00 My2
pick 17e4289 O1
pick 73b8f2e O2

# Rebase aab4d7f..73b8f2e onto aab4d7f
#
# Commands:
#  pick = use commit
#  edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

You'll be dropped back into that commit. Fix the bug and then `git add` the newly edited file back onto the commit and then do a `git commit --amend`. You might want to update your commit message.

I believe the rebase will then automatically continue after the ammend. If it doesn't try `git rebase --continue`.

You may then need to resolve conflicts in the later commits with the changed code, but hopefully git sorts it all out on it's own.

You should then be able to push this back to the central repo and others should get the changes with their next pull.

**WARNING:**

I really only recommend this if simply fixing it in the newest version is not considered acceptable in your environment. Rebasing can get tricky. It's certainly okay to make a backup of your repo before playing around like this. If at any point during the rebase you feel something has gone wrong the best (i.e. safest) thing to do is to run `git rebase --abort` and start again.

Comment: I'm not sure how you plan to do this without rewriting the history. You either fix it in the present and leave it in the history, or rebase your fix in / remove your commits and rewrite the history. I don't see how you can have it both ways.

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot rewrite the history?

Comment: I cannot rewrite the history since it is already published to a central repository and other developers may have pulled from it already

Comment: And when they pull again they will get the changes and can resolve any conflicts.

Comment: I don't think this will work if they have some local commits based on the now invalid commits. Even if it does, it can wreck havoc. I want to work harder, not make other developers work hard.

Answer (score 0):

You say the changes in `fix`, which you built on top of `My2` conflict with the changes in `My1'` and `My2'`.

The first thing to say is : if it would conflict, then git will detect the conflict during the merge operation, and let you a chance to edit the conflicting files, so that you can keep the correct version.

Second : even if the merge commit does not behave as you would like, you can correct the code, and add an extra commit on top of it.

Finally : call `merge` with the `--no-commit` option. Then you can check that the merge behaved properly, fix it if needed, and commit the lot - without any extra commit.

In case the merge has discarded changes from your fix in the file `path/file.ext`, you can always get the content back, using

```
git checkout fix -- path/file.ext
```

Comment: I'm not saying they conflict. To git they are very reasonable. E.g. My1 added file Foo, then My1' removes file Foo. So when I merge, Foo will be removed from my branch. No conflict, and yet this is not what I want. Fixing the merge in this case means reimplementing the whole feature. I'm just looking for a way for the merge to not include My1' and My2' (or create the branch in a way that will not remove the feature after merging)

Answer (score -3):

Just check the file out and fix the bug!

--Update--
I'm not sure anyone is going to read my explanation here, but perhaps a few people will and I might get back to 0.

I don't see why my suggestion is so awful.  A great deal of developers time is wasted on a silly things like trying to remove a commit from a source code repository because you put a bug in.  The whole point of a source code repository is that you can see where you introduced the bug, see what the bug is and now you can fix the bug and move on.

Why would you want to remove it from the repository, its historical.

Don't waste your time trying to fix the Repo. Fix the Bug!

Comment: Some places work under the idea (so I hear) that any commit should be deploy-able. It may be that this is serious enough to consider that it has to be completely removed. I also get the sense that he's looking to remove it asap and add a fix in later, but I don't see how he can do that without editing the history.

Comment: I've always found the concept that ever commit should be deployable to be very unfortunate as it prevents proper use of source control by restricting when people can commit, which in my opinion is a bad thing. :)  Thanks for the comment.